# Remote connect to mongodb - cannot connect

Tags: mongodb, server, connect

I am trying to remote connect to mongodb. The mongodb server is running on my desktop, and needs to be access by a javascript app which can run on any device.

Steps i have taken so far:

```
#1 Openned port 27017 for listening on in the operating system

#2 Edited the config file commenting out #bindIp: 0.0.0.0 and replacing with the desktop 
static ip #bindIp: 192.168.1.xxx and added security: authorization: 'enabled'

#3 Created an admin user in the admin database on mongodb use admin 
db.createUser({ user: 'name', pwd: 'password', roles: [{ role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', 
db:'admin'}]

#4 Tested the above login locally on the desktop and access is granted

#5 Restarted the mongodb service

#6 The connection string is use "mongodb://name:password@192.168.1.xxx"
```

However i still am unable to remotely connect to the database. I have looked everywhere for help and read the documentation, can someone please point out what i'm doing wrong or provide a link to a resource that gives a step by step guide how to remote connect, please. It would be much appritiated.

Comment: So, would you like to access on Intranet or Internet?

Comment: Intranet is what im mainly after for this app

Comment: You just commented our bindIp but still you are binding onto your desktop machine online. That's why only desktop can connect.
To get access from other local network you have to set it to 0.0.0.0

bindIp: 0.0.0.0

Comment: like this: net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  #bindIp: 192.168.1.xxx
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

Comment: I did what you said in the config file however still unable to connect over the intranet remotely

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Have you allowed port 27017 to be accessible in your firewall?

Comment: I managed to configure it to work thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

Use `authSource=admin` if you get any permission issue, like this:

URL: `mongodb://admin:admin@192.168.1.X:27017/Database?authSource=admin`

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank for the answer but unfortunately no joy. It's really grinding my as i would rather use a nosql db instead of a relational one :( i guess i might just have to use trusty mssql server lol

Comment: Great choice ;)